# Lost session to Ubuntu upgrade 18.04.LTS sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, 18.04

While upgrading to 18.04 LTS, I was asked the question

```
Configuration file '/etc/sysctl.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sysctl.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and now I can't restart the process, giving me

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

I tried to  `sudo screen -D -r`, but screen is not installed and my machine won't let me install it saying

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Arul Selvan for [your post](https://serverfault.com/questions/387547/how-do-i-reattach-to-ubuntu-servers-do-release-upgrade-process).

Tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

So what I got after reboot was a black screen.

Created a install usb disk and booted it up, created a boot repair log

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/M2yv3dXjqs/

Not sure how to proceed. If I go to repair it says

> The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit ([www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd)), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

So what I did was changed the BIOS to EFI mode on the usb disk, rebooted into the live disk and installed boot-repair again.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

and it fixed my issue.